# Pairing via Bluetooth Framework on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, device

I've read every article I can find here and elsewhere regarding use of the Bluetooth Framework private API on iOS.  I've been successful with discovery and connection of 2.1 BT devices using code based upon the BeeTee app (https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee -- thank you, Michael Dorner) that otherwise do not appear when scanning using the standard BT system app.  But the ability to pair with one of these devices escapes me.  It appears I must use a "pairing agent" but have found no docs that have been helpful.  This app will not be submitted to the app store so that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear that pairing requires Apple's authentification chip on the Bluetooth hardware side.
See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26377218/1864294).

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion.  All my research led to determining that, via the External Accessory Program, Apple requires hardware vendors to pass through their approval program and, it appears, actually requires inclusion of a chip and/or firmware/hardware specs dictated by Apple.

Comment: There is an update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579226/connecting-to-other-bluetooth-device-by-beetee-app/26377218#26377218