# Connecting to other Bluetooth Device by BeeTee app

Tags: ios, bluetooth, iphone-privateapi

I need to implement a self bluetooth app to connect with all bluetooth devices to iPhone. I know it is not possible with CoreBluetooth framework.

I use private API and added header files of DeviceManager and BluetoothManager to private frameworks and downloaded BeeTee Project from [here](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee)

This app runs and finds all bluetooth device near me but when I have tried to connect to a device by this code:

```
[self.bluetoothManager connectDevice:bluetoothDevice];
```

and this

```
[bluetoothDevice connect];
```

When a cell is selected, Both of above codes request to connect but BTM returns this message:

> BeeTee[5473:60b] BTM: connection to service 0xffffffff on device "Nokia 500" F4:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx failed with error 109

What is error 109? Which would be set service number?

I guess I should pair devices before connecting but how can I do that?

Comment: @Gilad_Gr Could you help me about this question?

Comment: I have got same Problem. Could anyone help me about this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just guessing, but I think the problem is that the `BluetoothManager.framework` is made for the [External Accessory Program by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html). And this allows (among others) SPP Bluetooth connection to **certificated** devices. But there is the problem: you need to have a device with a authentication chip inside.

I don't know on which level/layer Apple implemented the authentication, but I fear the did it one layer under the private framework BeeTee is using.

UPDATE: Maybe this is helpful for you:

```
BluetoothManager *bluetoothManager = //...
[bluetoothManager setDevicePairingEnabled:YES];
[bluetoothManager connectDevice:bluetoothDevice withServices:0x00002000];
```

[Credits](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee/issues/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
BluetoothManager *bluetoothManager = //...
[bluetoothManager setDevicePairingEnabled:YES];
[btManager setPincode:@"111111" forDevice:bluetoothDevice.deviceRef];
//where 111111 is your device PIN
[bluetoothManager connectDevice:bluetoothDevice withServices:0x00002000];
```

Comment: In above code where to get the bluetoothDevice and device pin .